# How can I create a slider that would display date, and is there a way to make markers appear in the website depending on the position of the slider?

Tags: javascript, html, date, slider

I have been struggling for the past day at creating a slider which would simply display a date, for some reason when I write `input type="date"` instead of `input type="range"` the slider always stops working. Can anyone please show me a sample code for a slider that displays a date?

Also another thing I was wondering about whether it is possible to display or hide images/markers/text in the website depending on the position of the slider? For example if I add an image of a map in my website, can I make different markers appear and disappear on this map with the use of the slider? If this is indeed possible, please point me towards resources where I could read up on about this!

Edit:
Sorry for not adding my attempts, here they are. This is based on some slider I found on the internet. This is the example of the slider with `input type="date"` that doesn't work. If I change it to `input type="range"` it starts to work again.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<h1>Slider</h1>
<p>Slidertext</p>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="date" min="1900-1-1" max="1910-1-1" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, show your attempts

Comment: I edited the original post to add my attempt

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in the one post. If you have another question, post another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a range input and then use its value to set the value of the date input. The min and max values of the range should be based on the number of days in the date range, which are retrieved from the date input's min and max values.

Do the reverse to set the range slider based on changes to the date.

```js
// Parse date in YYYY-MM-DD format as local date
function parseISOLocal(s) {
  let [y, m, d] = s.split('-');
  return new Date(y, m - 1, d);
}

// Format date as YYYY-MM-DD
function dateToISOLocal(date) {
  let z = n => ('0' + n).slice(-2);
  return date.getFullYear() + '-' + z(date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + z(date.getDate());
}

// Convert range slider value to date string
function range2date(evt) {
  let dateInput = document.querySelector('#d0');
  let minDate = parseISOLocal(dateInput.defaultValue);
  minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + Number(this.value));
  dateInput.value = dateToISOLocal(minDate);
}

// Convert entered date to range
function date2range(evt) {
  let date = parseISOLocal(this.value);
  let numDays = (date - new Date(this.min)) / 8.64e7;
  document.querySelector('#r0').value = numDays;
}

window.onload = function() {
  let rangeInput = document.querySelector('#r0');
  let dateInput = document.querySelector('#d0');
  // Get the number of days from the date min and max
  // Dates in YYYY-MM-DD format are treated as UTC 
  // so will be exact whole days
  let rangeMax = (new Date(dateInput.max) - new Date(dateInput.min)) / 8.64e7;
  // Set the range min and max values
  rangeInput.min = 0;
  rangeInput.max = rangeMax;
  // Add listener to set the date input value based on the slider
  rangeInput.addEventListener('input', range2date, false);
  // Add listener to set the range input value based on the date
  dateInput.addEventListener('change', date2range, false);
}
```

```html
<input id="r0" type="range" min="0" max="3652" value="0"><br>
<input id="d0" type="date" min="1900-01-01" max="1910-01-01" value="1900-01-01">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! Could you please point me towards some information where I could learn how can I now make different markers or information appear or dissapear based on the date that is on the slider?